# d3.csv with two-word key columns

Tags: html, d3.js

I am using a csv file where some of the keys are two-words (separated by a white space).
I want to load the csv file using d3.csv but could not figure out how to reference the data in the two-word columns (using d.key.)

This code does display nothing:

```
svg.selectAll("circle").transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("cx",function(d) {return x(+d.percent obese 2000);})
    .attr("cy",function(d) {return y(+d.percent obese 2000);})
    .attr("r",5)
```

Could anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parentheses and quotes:

```
.attr("cx",function(d) {return x(+d["Percent Obese 2007"]);})
...
```

Comment: This is how it looks like on an excel sheet:
State     Percent Obese 2007 Percent Obese 2006  
Colorado 19.3            18.2 
Massachusetts 21.7            20.3 
Connecticut 21.7            20.6 
Rhode Island 21.7            21.4 
Vermont 21.9 21.2            20.2 
Utah 22.4 21.9            21.2 
Montana 22.6 21.2            21.3 
California 23.3            23.3

Comment: Ok, so there's 2 words and a number in each header? Does d["Percent Obese 2007"] work?

Comment: For some reason it did not work at first. But now it does!!
Thanks a lot man.
I could have kept the '.' after d

Comment: I'll update the answer. Remember that the case of the letters is important.

Answer (score 1):

In my case with V4, I was using `return +d["marker-color"]`; to call a hexadecimal colour but it didn't work.

I found that `return d["marker-color"];` works